# Arduino Mega to 2x UNO over Serial

Tags: serialization

Hi This is my first time posting, so bear with me.

My problem is with the serial communication between the Arduino Mega and 2x Arduino UNO's.

My setup comprises of a Mega as my master device and  1x UNO + Adafruit sound shield & 1x UNO + Adafruit Motor Shield. I have them via serial port i.e Serial1 RxTx on the mega to Serial TxRx on the UNO and same again for Serial2 for the other UNO, (I have x2 UNO's as both sheilds take up the whole PWM pin of the UNO)

```
Serial.begin(9600); //<--mega//
Serial1.begin(9600); //<--mega//
Serial2.begin(9600); //<--mega//
Serial.begin(9600); //<--UNO Sound//
Serial.begin(9600); //<--UNO motor//
```

Mega code:

```
 Serial.println("Entering While loop1");              // Debug //

  while(CommFlag1 == 0){


    while (Serial2.available()){

         SerialReceive2 = Serial2.read();
         RxContent2.concat(SerialReceive2);                                                    //Store Content of Serial Data into Global Variable//
         delay(10);  
    }


    Serial.print("Sound MCU: ");                                                      // Debug //
    Serial.println(RxContent2);                                                       // Debug //
    delay(100);                                                                       // Debug //




    if (RxContent2 == "Alive$$$") {
      Serial2.println("CommEst");
      Serial.println("Alive Response Recieved Sound MCU");                            // Debug //
      RxContent2 = "";
      CommFlag1 = 1;
      }
   }


      Serial.println("Entering While loop2");                                            // Debug //

      while(CommFlag2 == 0){

        while (Serial1.available()){
          SerialReceive1 = Serial1.read();                                  //Store Content of Serial Data into Global Variable//
          RxContent1.concat(SerialReceive1);
          delay(10);     
        }

          Serial.print("Motor MCU: ");                                               // Debug //                              
          Serial.println(RxContent1);                                                  // Debug //
          delay(100);                                                                  // Debug //

          if (RxContent1 == "Alive"){
            Serial1.println("CommEst");
            Serial.println("Alive Response Recieved Motor MCU");
            RxContent1 = "";
            CommFlag2 = 1;
            }
        }
```

UNO Code(Both are the same except the Serial.print statement which is Alive for the motor):

```
Serial.println("Alive$$$");

while(CommFlag == 0){

delay(250);
  while (Serial.available()){
         SerialReceive = Serial.read();
         RxContent.concat(SerialReceive);
          delay(50);


      if (RxContent == "CommEst"){

        CommFlag = 1;
        RxContent = "";

      }
  } 
}
```

In the serial window I can see the UNO's "alive$$$" response when PC is connected to the USB (Serial) on the mega, but the mega doesn't seem to accept the response value and doesn't execute the if statement?

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Rich

Answer (score 0):

In UNO code you send string by using Serial.println(), That means the string is prefix by \r\n character. But when you compare is not ending with \r\n. Please change if statement by add \r\n at the end of compare string.

```
if (RxContent2 == "Alive$$$\r\n")
```

and

```
if (RxContent1 == "Alive\r\n")
```

Or change code in UNO to print not println

```
Serial.print("Alive$$$");
```

and

```
Serial.print("Alive");
```

Comment: Hi Adisak, a belated thank you for your suggestion I have finally tried this and now it works on the UNO that's doing the sound control but I haven't been able to get to work on the UNO that is doing the motor control. 

The only difference between the two is that the sound UNO is in a subroutine which is executed after turning on the serial port in setup and the motor is not a subroutine and directly follows the initialisation of the serial port? 

Do you think this would make a difference?

Comment: motor uno code: 
Serial.println("Alive"); 

master control code:
 if (RxContent1 == "Alive\r\n"){.....} 

I have this following code in the master control so I can see what is coming from the motor uno
Serial.print("Motor MCU: ");
Serial.println(RxContent1);

What I am getting on the serial window is:

Motor MCU:
Alive

It’s as if its receiving a \r\n preceding the incoming text string but my code shouldn’t be doing this? 
What do you think could be the cause? Or could this be a timing issue from initialising the serial port?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Rich